# Working with multiple docker-compose files in the same application

Tags: docker

I'm currently building an application behind Docker and before I invest heavily into my apps CICD flow, I want to get some of the most important functionality working.

I'm using a service for user authentication, however whenever I run my docker-compose file, my server will be restarted, resulting in a ~30 second downtime in my application. I don't want this and so to avoid having to build a CICD flow to cater for this, I've created a second docker-compose file which I will only run when my server NEEDS to be updated

```
#rest of app - docker-compose.yml file
version: '3'
services:
  angular:
    build:
      context: /angular

#server i don't want going down constantly - docker-compose-server.yml
version: '3'
services: 
 keycloak:
    build:
      context: /keycloak
```

However with this approach, whenever I run my docker-compose.yml file, I get a warning telling me that my keycloak container is orphaned and vise versa.

Could this lead to problems down the line? How do I go about getting rid of this warning as I assume it's something I want to avoid. Also, these files are both in the same directory and so it seems that they are on the same docker network. Does this sound correct?

Comment: If you're starting to ask questions like this, more involved systems like Kubernetes are a significant investment, but do basically solve this class of problem out of the box.

Comment: Docker Compose is not meant to run production-ready deployments like these. As @DavidMaze mentioned, container orchestrations tools like Kubernetes are needed. Then, you can implement a blue-green deployment workflow (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) to minimize / eliminate downtime. (Other techniques exists, but that's the most common one)

Comment: In Kubernetes, even without implementing a blue/green or canary-type workflow, just updating a Deployment spec to a new image will do a no-downtime rolling upgrade.

Comment: what do you mean by "run my docker-compose file"? you can stop/up/restart individual services with commands like `docker-compose restart angular` which won't affect other services in the dc.conf file.